# Schemeでリストのリストの要素を処理するには？

Tags: scheme

schemeにおいて、あるリストが((商品番号a 単価a 購入個数a) (商品番号b 単価b 購入個数b)....)のように定義されているとき、
この購入個数の単価の和を求める関数はどのように記述するべきでしょうか。

リストを関数の引数にわたすところまでは分かりますが、リストを取り出して、和を計算する処理の書き方がわかりません。

Answer (score 2):

以下は `cadr` と `apply` を使う方法です。

```lisp
(define lst '((1 100 10) (2 250 5) (3 500 3)))
(apply + (map cadr lst))
=>
850
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。リストの最後の要素を取り出すにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？car, cadrでもなく。

Comment: その場合は `last` を使います。`(map last lst)`

Comment: たびたびありがとうございました！